# Validez del pedido, según el día en el que estamos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy haciendo una tienda online. La cuestión es que depende en el día que se hace el pedido el contrato tendrá una validez un día u otro.

Por ejemplo:

Si el pedido se hace entre el día 8 y el día 24 el contrato entrara en vigor el día 1 del mes siguiente.
Pero si por lo contrario el día que se hace el pedido es entre el día 25 y el día 7, el contrato entrara en vigor el mes siguiente el día 15 ("menos si esta entre el 1 y el 7, que seria el día 15 también")

Yo estoy haciendo las siguientes pruebas.

```
$diaactual = date("d");
  if ($diaactual = 8 && $diaactual <=24){
    $opt->fecha_contrato = 8;
  }else{
    $opt->fecha_contrato = 25;
  }
```

Esto parece que me esta funcionando bien, pero en lugar de guardar 8 o 24 quiero guardar el `d-m-Y"` como puedo hacerlo? no se me ocurre como decirle el mes que viene y poner yo el día, y sobre todo la opción entre el día 25 y el 7, ya que puede ser el mes siguiente el vigor del contrato o el mismo día.

Alguna sugerencia.

**Lo he solucionado así:**

```
$diaactual = date("d");

  if ($diaactual >= 8 && $diaactual <=24){
    $opt->fecha_contrato = date("1-m-Y",strtotime(date("d-m-Y")."+ 1 month"));
  }elseif ($diaactual >= 25 && $diaactual <=31){
    $opt->fecha_contrato = date("15-m-Y",strtotime(date("d-m-Y")."+ 1 month"));
  }elseif ($diaactual >= 1 && $diaactual <=7){
    $opt->fecha_contrato = date("15-m-Y");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utiliza la clase Carbon:
Así se guardaría como un timestamp, como created_at, etc.

```
$diaactual = date("d");
  if ($diaactual = 8 && $diaactual <=24){
    $opt->fecha_contrato = Carbon::now()->addMonths(1)->startOfMonth();
  }else{
    $opt->fecha_contrato = Carbon::now()->addMonths(1)->startOfMonth()->addDays(14);
  }
```

```
$diaactual = date("d");
  if ($diaactual = 8 && $diaactual <=24){
    $opt->fecha_contrato = Carbon::now()->addMonths(1)->startOfMonth()->format('d-m-Y');
  }else{
    $opt->fecha_contrato = Carbon::now()->addMonths(1)->startOfMonth()->addDays(14)->format('d-m-Y');
  }
```

EDIT con forma 100% Carbon:

```
$ocho = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addDays(7);
$veinticuatro = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addDays(23);
if(Carbon::now()->betweenIncluded($ocho, $veinticuatro)){
   $opt->fecha_contrato = Carbon::now()->addMonth()->startOfMonth()->format('d-m-Y');
}
elseif(Carbon::now()->betweenExcluded($veinticuatro, Carbon::now()->addMonth()->startOfMonth() )){
   $opt->fecha_contrato = Carbon::now()->addMonth()->startOfMonth()->addDays(14)->format('d-m-Y');
}
elseif(Carbon::now()->betweenExcluded( Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth(),$ocho)){
   $opt->fecha_contrato = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addDays(14)->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

Puede parecer algo mareante, pero la sintaxis es bastante explicita (en inglés), En este caso no puede haber muchos problemas con tu solución, pero si hicieras más modificaciones en las fechas, imaginate controlar todo el tema de los años bisiestos, semanas, etc. Carbon te incluye todo esto en Laravel :)

Espero te sea de ayuda ;)

Comment: Hola @ItsEdgar94 parece interesante tu solución.Puedes revisar mi pregunta, coloque una solución sobre todo teniendo en cuenta el periodo del 1 al 7 que la fecha vigor es 15 del mismo mes

Comment: @Miguel voy a modificar mi respuesta y voy a añadir una solución utilizando solamente Carbon, tu solución debería ser suficiente, pero me gustaría que le dieras un intento a las funciones que te facilita Laravel ;)

Comment: Ok! modifica y la marco como correcta, siempre es bueno saber varias formas y más si son nativas de Laravel

Comment: Modificado @Miguel ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, funciona perfectamente!

Answer (score 0):

Como te han comentado anteriormente la opcion es usar Carbon, solo le haria una correcion a la sugerencia anterior, YO NO TE LA RECOMENDARIA usar

```
Carbon::now()->addMonths(1)->startOfMonth(); 
Carbon::now()->addMonths(1)->startOfMonth()->addDays(14);
```

(ejemplo: si carbon:now() es 31 de enero, el resultado final seria 15 de marzo, en vez de 15 de febrero)

(esto tiene un problema muy grave sobre todo si el siguiente mes NO TIENE el dia actual sobre todo dia 30 o 31 que es el caso mas comun)

Mi recomendacion es que primero hagas el startOfMonth() y luego sumas el mes

```
Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addMonths(1); 
Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addMonths(1)->addDays(14);
```

Checalo ojala confirmes que te funciona.